# I am looking for the customers who visited both location (Santa Clara, Milpitas)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have customer table and it contains -

```
Customer_ID     Location     Store_Entry
1               Milpitas      2019-10-01
2               Santa Clara   2019-10-01  
3               Sunnyvale     2019-10-01
2               Santa Clara   2019-10-01
1               Sunnyvale     2019-10-01
2               Milpitas      2019-10-01
```

Output should be - Customer_ID = 2

My Query is -

```
SELECT Location,COUNT(Customer_ID) AS TOTAL_CUS
FROM `Customer`
WHERE Location IN ('Santa Clara','Milpitas')
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(Customer_Id)= 2
```

My output is -

```
Location   TOTAL_CUS
Santa Clara  2
Milpitas     2
```

Comment: You've tagged this with three different database systems. Which one are you actually using?

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> customers who visited both location (Santa Clara, Milpitas)

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT Customer_ID
FROM `project.dataset.Customer` 
WHERE Location IN ('Santa Clara', 'Milpitas')
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Location) = 2
```

Comment: Awesome Thank you Mikhail ... Just qq .. It's quite confusing to me last part why we are saying location =2 ? Why are not saying Location =1 or 3 something like this? Any kind of guidance is really helpful! Thanks

Comment: 2 means you are looking for customer who have both distinct locations ('Santa Clara' and 'Milpitas') visited. thus `=2`

Comment: Great .. So if we are looking for three locations it means we can use location=3, Am I right? Thanks again!